# Coredns in pending state in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm, kubelet

I am trying to configure a 2 node Kubernetes cluster. First I am trying to configure the master node of the cluster on a CentOS VM. I have initialized the cluster using 'kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=172.16.100.6 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16' and deployed the flannel network to the cluster. But when I do 'kubectl get nodes', I get the following output ----

```
[root@kubernetus ~]# kubectl get nodes
NAME         STATUS     ROLES    AGE   VERSION
kubernetus   NotReady   master   57m   v1.12.0
```

Following is the output of 'kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide ' ----

```
[root@kubernetus ~]# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE     NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP             NODE         NOMINATED NODE
kube-system   coredns-576cbf47c7-9x59x             0/1     Pending   0          58m   <none>         <none>       <none>
kube-system   coredns-576cbf47c7-l52wc             0/1     Pending   0          58m   <none>         <none>       <none>
kube-system   etcd-kubernetus                      1/1     Running   2          57m   172.16.100.6   kubernetus   <none>
kube-system   kube-apiserver-kubernetus            1/1     Running   2          57m   172.16.100.6   kubernetus   <none>
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kubernetus   1/1     Running   1          57m   172.16.100.6   kubernetus   <none>
kube-system   kube-proxy-hr557                     1/1     Running   1          58m   172.16.100.6   kubernetus   <none>
kube-system   kube-scheduler-kubernetus            1/1     Running   1          57m   172.16.100.6   kubernetus   <none>
```

coredns is in a pending state for a very long time. I have removed docker and kubectl, kubeadm, kubelet a no of times & tried to recreate the cluster, but every time it shows the same output. Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: First step for any problem is to get the logs - use `kubectl logs podname --namespace=kube-system` and also check if there is something in the events with the `kubectl get events --namespace=kube-system` command.

Comment: I have two coredns pods which are in pending state . Hence I tried ' kubectl logs coredns-576cbf47c7-9x59x --namespace=kube-system ' and 'kubectl logs coredns-576cbf47c7-l52wc --namespace=kube-system' but it did'nt show any output .

Comment: For the command 'kubectl get events --namespace=kube-system' , I got some warnings ---- 62m         Warning   FailedScheduling    Pod          0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate. 88m         Warning   Unhealthy           Pod          Liveness probe failed: Get https://172.16.100.6:6443/healthz: net/http: TLS handsh
ake timeout. 88m         Warning   Unhealthy           Pod          Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 403

Comment: I also tried systemctl status kubelet -l and there were some errors --- Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d ..... Oct 02 19:21:32 kubernetus kubelet[19007]: E1002 19:21:32.886170   19007 kubelet.go:2167] Container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized

Comment: Is that really `kubernetus`?

Comment: The commands itself show its kubernetes !!!

Comment: problem fixed?? @AdityaDatta

Comment: First setup container n/w using calico or any other solution to put your coreDNS in ready state.

Answer (score 13):

Try to install Pod network add-on (Base on [this guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network)).

Run this line:

```sh
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.14/manifests/calico.yaml
```

Answer (score 4):

> Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d .....
>   Oct 02 19:21:32 kubernetus kubelet[19007]: E1002 19:21:32.886170 19007
>   kubelet.go:2167] Container runtime network not ready:
>   NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker:
>   network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized

According to this error, you forgot to initialize a Kubernetes Pod network add-on. Looking at your settings, I suppose it should be Flannel.

Here is the instruction from the official Kubernetes documentation:

> For flannel to work correctly, you must pass
>   `--pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16` to kubeadm init.
>
> Set `/proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables` to 1 by running
>   `sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1` to pass bridged IPv4
>   traffic to iptables’ chains. This is a requirement for some CNI
>   plugins to work, for more information please see here.
>
> ```
> kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/v0.10.0/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
> ```
>
> Note that flannel works on amd64, arm, arm64 and ppc64le, but until
>   flannel v0.11.0 is released you need to use the following manifest
>   that supports all the architectures:
>
> ```
> kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/c5d10c8/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
> ```

For more information, you can visit this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#tabs-pod-install-4).

Comment: Thanks for the info. You are absolutely right . I had applied the flannel network and there was no error in it . I used ' kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml ' to apply flannel network but when it did not work I used the above 'kubectl apply' commands which you have provided but the situation was same. This is an issue with kubernetes version 1.12 . That's why I used kubernetes version 1.11.0  and it is working properly now . I don't know what is the issue with version 1.12 but old versions are running successfully .

Comment: But according to your `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide`, you had no Flannel Pods

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I had applied flannel network on my cluster using all the three 'kubectl apply' syntaxes and I did not get any error while executing this command but it was not reflecting there . However , when I backtracked to version 1.11.0, then the cluster was configured properly . Now I have three flannel pods ----- one for master & two for slave nodes .

Comment: I am using Kubernetes 1.12 and I am running into this isssue. I have setup Flannel using the `kubectl apply` syntax from the documentation but coredns pods are not starting up.

Comment: It seems that this message appears when one has not yet joined a node to the master. I think the documentation is misleading in this case because it states: *And once the CoreDNS pod is up and running, you can continue by joining your nodes.* Which let me to understand that I need to get the flannel cluster network setup before I can join a node to the master.

Answer (score 2):

For the Kubernetes cluster to be available, the cluster should have a Container Networking Interface (CNI). A pod-network is required to be configured for the dns pod to be functional.

Install any of the CNI Providers like:
 - Flannel 
 - Calico 
 - Canal
 - WeaveNet, etc.,

Without this, the hosted Kubernetes cluster would have the master in the NotReady State.

Answer (score 0):

Check if docker and kubernetes are using the same cgroup driver.
I faced the same issue (CentOS 7, kubernetes v1.14.1), and setting same cgroup driver (systemd) fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I installed kubernetes with 1 master + 1 work-node.
After I made `kubeadm init ...`, I faced two issues:

1. On the master node, the coredns were pending.
2. On the work-node, kubectl command didn't work out

On the work-node, I did the following and fixed the both issues:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube

sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf $HOME/.kube/config

sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config**
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I've restarted the system and re-applied calico.yaml, coredns and calico pods started creating.

Answer (score 0):

take this solution at least priority and try changing instance type (preferably higher cpu core/ram)
in my case i have changed linux instance t3.micro to t2.medium and its works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).